# Google Play has removed my app, but I can't find the offending lines in the Manifest?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services

Sorry if this isn't the right place to post this, I don't find myself in this part of the internet very often haha.

So awhile back Google sent out those emails regarding apps being taken down if they use certain permissions relating to calls and SMS usage. I may have ignored said emails for a bit too long, and well, here we are.

The problem is, I'm not by any means a good programmer, especially with Java. Long story short, the only places I can find the offending lines is in the manifest class file, which of course I can't change. I don't see them in the xml file.

Is there a different place I should be looking, generally speaking? The code is a bit hacky and most of it was already written when I got ahold of it, which is why I'm hoping someone can kind of just point me in the right direction if nothing else.

In the email I received, the specific permissions were READ_CALL_LOG and WRITE_CALL_LOG. The only thing that would be remotely related (that I can find) is read_contacts.

Responses are appreciated!

Comment: Most probably the problem is in `WRITE_CALL_LOG` , BTW why you need that permission??

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find them in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file then chances are the permission is coming from a 3rd party library you use.

There's a [whole page of documentation here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge) on how this works in Android Studio. If you want to see where the permissions came from, [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts) say how to do this:

> Even before you build your APK, you can see a preview of what your merged manifest looks by opening your AndroidManifest.xml file in Android Studio, and then clicking the Merged Manifest tab at the bottom of the editor.
>
> The Merged Manifest view shows the results of the merged manifest on the left and information about each merged manifest file on the right, as shown in figure 2. The elements that were merged in from lower-priority manifest files are highlighted in different colors on the left. The key for each color is specified under Manifest Sources on the right.